# How to check the number of articles with a keyword in The Guardian newspaper using API key?

Tags: python, json, api-key

I am quite new in Python and I am trying to run a piece of code that can check the number of articles mentioning a keyword in The Guardian's newspaper.

It is something that I have already done with the New York Times, but when I try to apply the same code to The Guardian, it says that line 8 (the one below) fails:

```
hits = json_res["response"]["meta"]["hits"]
```

This is the entire piece of code I have problems with (I have previously defined the guardian_api_key):

```
#Checking number of articles on a topic in The Guardian
import requests
def number_of_articles(api_key,keyword,begin_date="19800101",end_date="20240101"):
    url_query = f"http://content.guardianapis.com/#/search?q={keyword}&begin_date={begin_date}&end_date={end_date}&api-key={api_key}"
    print (url_query)
    res = requests.get(url_query)
    json_res = res.json()
    hits = json_res["response"]["meta"]["hits"]
    return hits

print(number_of_articles(api_key=guardian_api_key,keyword="vote"))
```

I would love to have some help so that I can understand what is going on! Please tell me if my question is unclear or what could I try.

Comment: Please share the full error message. Just a guess - your dictionary does not contain the fields you are trying to access.

Comment: @N3wbie Thank you very much for commenting! This is the error message: 
Cell In[49], line 11
      8     hits = json_res["response"]["meta"]["hits"]
      9     return hits
---> 11 print(number_of_articles(api_key=guardian_api_key,keyword="vote"))

Cell In[49], line 8, in number_of_articles(api_key, keyword, begin_date, end_date)
      6 res = requests.get(url_query)
      7 json_res = res.json()
----> 8 hits = json_res["response"]["meta"]["hits"]
      9 return hits
KeyError: 'response'

Comment: The Guardians API is different to the New York Times API, hence it is very likely that you get another JSON object back from both APIs. And this is what the error message is about. You are trying to access a field in the dictionary called `response` which does not exist. If you want to handle both APIs you need to parse both request results differently. The first thing to do is to print out the JSON object and analyze the parts you are interested in. Then, you could write different parsers for different APIs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the Gurdians URL, change it from

`f"http://content.guardianapis.com/#/search?`

to

`f"https://content.guardianapis.com/search?`

In contrast to The Times, the number of articles found by the search is  stored in

`res["response"]["total"]`

If you are open to suggestions, I would write your code more modularly, allowing you to add further APIs to your system.

```
import requests
class BaseParser:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.base_url= ""

    def query(self, params: dict) -> dict:
        query = self.base_url
        for key,val in params.items():
            query += f"&{key}={val}"
        return requests.get(query).json()

class GuardianParser(BaseParser):

    def __init__(self, key):
        super().__init__(key)
        self.base_url= f"https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key={self.key}"

    def number_of_articles(self, params: dict) -> int:
        res = self.query(params)
        return res["response"]["total"]

class TimesParser(BaseParser):

    def __init__(self, key):
        super().__init__(key)
        self.base_url= f"the api url from the times"

    def number_of_articles(self, params: dict):
        res = self.query(params)
        return res["response"]["meta"]["hits"]

search_dict = {
    "keyword":"vote",
    "begin_date":19800101,
    "end_date":20240101
}

gparser = GuardianParser(gkey)
gart = gparser.number_of_articles(search_dict)
tparser = TimesParser(tkey)
tart = gparser.number_of_articles(search_dict)
print(f"Guardian number of articles: {gart}")
print(f"The Times number of articles: {tart}")
```

In addition, I would add some error handling, too (e.g. expiring API key, bad request, unreachable API etc.). This would go beyond the scope of the question, tho.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your correction was extremely useful and my code works! I am of course open to suggestions: I will try out your more modular code. Thank you again for taking the time to answer, you helped me a lot

Comment: @RebecaOdC if you like my answer you can also up vote it :)

Comment: Rest assured, I will vote it up once I have enough reputation to do so! :)